# Publish Azure Web Role Without SSL Cert Fails

Tags: azure, ssl, publish

I have an azure web role project that for the production site has an ssl cert, let's call it https://www.myapp.com. I have no issues with publishing this and it works as expected.

However, for testing purposes, we have another site spun up that we don't need ssl on. It runs on the default azure site name, http://myapp-test.cloudapp.net. Ever since I added the cert for the production configuration, the test publish refuses to run, stating that the cert isn't added on the target Azure deployment. This makes sense, I haven't added the cert to the test site. However, trying to remove the test configuration for the certificate throws another error, as the csdef file has defined a certificate and not providing one in the test config prevents the publish.

How do I setup a configuration with the cert and one without the cert?

Below is my production configuration, with sensitive data removed.

```
<Role name="MyApp">
<Instances count="1" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="" />
  <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="" />
  <Setting name="ServiceBusConnectionString" value="" />
  <Setting name="ENVIRONMENT" value="production" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="MyAppSSL" thumbprint="thumbprint value" thumbprintAlgorithm="" />
</Certificates>
```

And the test configuration:

```
<Role name="MyApp">
<Instances count="1" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="data" />
  <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="data" />
  <Setting name="ServiceBusConnectionString" value="" />
  <Setting name="ENVIRONMENT" value="staging" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
<!-- removing the certificate config prevents the publish from happening, but including it also prevents the publish since I don't have the cert on the test site-->
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something in your problem description, but why can't you just remove the cert reference from the CSDEF?

Comment: If I do that, I don't have a reference to the cert for the production deployment and the site won't be running with SSL.

Comment: In that case, why not add the cert to your testing site, regardless of if you are actually going to use it or not?  Or create a dummy self-signed cert that you upload to the testing site and then update the CSCFG with that dummy cert thumbprint.

Comment: @kwill I ended up going with the dummy self signed cert. If you can add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Added as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a dummy self-signed cert that you upload to the testing site and then update the CSCFG with that dummy cert thumbprint.